# How to make sure certain added elements stay on right side of the screen bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using javascript to add a set of fields every time a user clicks on add fields.

I am using a bootstrap grid.

The area on the left side behaves good. When I add fields on the right side it jumps over and starts adding it on the bottom of the div like so:

[image: Default]

This is the code:

**Main view**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row create-form">
    <%= simple_form_for @vacancy do |f| %>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <%= f.hidden_field :recruiter_id, value: current_recruiter.id %>
        <%= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "job title"%>
        <%= f.input :address, label: false, placeholder: "location", input_html: {id: "user_input_autocomplete_address" } %>
        <%= f.input :description, label: false, placeholder: "description", :input_html => {:rows => 7}  %>
        <%= f.input :jobtype_id, collection: Jobtype.all, label: false, prompt: "sector"%>
        <%= f.input :jobterm_id, collection: Jobterm.all, label: false, prompt: "Contract type"%>
        <%= f.input :wage_cents, label: false, placeholder: "wage (optional)" %>
      </div>


        <%= f.simple_fields_for :vacancyschedules do |vacancyschedule| %>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" id="vacancyschedules">
            <%= render "vacancyschedule_fields", f: vacancyschedule %>
          </div>
        <% end %>


      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add schedule', f, :vacancyschedules %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Partial (this is being rendered in the div with id vacancyschedules**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :start_hour, as: :time, default: Time.parse('09:00')%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :end_hour, as: :time, default: Time.parse('17:00')%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :start_date, placeholder: "start date", class: 'form-control', data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' }, label: false, error: false  %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "X", f %>
</div>
```

I tried tinkering a bit to make it work, and the "best" I've achieved so far is following behaviour:

[image]

I achieved this by adding some bootstrap columns to my partial:

```
<div class="nested-fields col-xs-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :start_hour, as: :time, default: Time.parse('09:00')%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :end_hour, as: :time, default: Time.parse('17:00')%>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 field"> 
    <%= f.text_field :start_date, placeholder: "start date", class: 'form-control', data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' }, label: false, error: false  %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "X", f %>
</div>
```

My reasoning behind these changes are that I thought the start date bar was pushing it below. And the wrapping element had to be half the screen. 
Also tried experimenting with float: right, but without succes.

Anyone has any tips to achieve this?

Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your mark-up, which might also explain some of the saving problems you are having: you have repeating `id` elements. An id is supposed to be unique in the html (and inside a form this is extra relevant, as things will be visibly there, but will not be posted to the server).

Now to handle your layout problem, I would have two md-6 columns, and make sure cocoon adds in the second column.

I write haml, which is a little less verbose and I find is a little clearer. So your view should look like:

```
.container
  .row.create-form
    = simple_form_for @vacancy do |f|
      .col-xs-12.col-md-6
        = # your fixed fields here

      #vacancy-schedules.col-xs-12.col-md-6
        = f.simple_fields_for :vacancyschedules do |vacancyschedule| 
          = render "vacancyschedule_fields", f: vacancyschedule
        = link_to_add_association 'add schedule', f, :vacancyschedules

      .actions
        = f.submit
```

It is a bit unclear in which column you want the submit button, I would place it in the first column, or in its own row at the end. Also I applied the `.col-xs-12.col-md-6` to both. Because my div is a container div, and not the size of the inserted partial. You still scale the inserted partials by adding a  `col-md-6` to your `.nested-fields`.